# Why does not calling `ValidateRect` cause a DirectX application to slow down tremendously?

Tags: windows, performance, winapi, directx

I asked [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281041/spot-the-flaw-c-code) earlier and realised that not calling `ValidateRect` in the application as response to `WM_PAINT` causes tremendous slowdown.

Why is this? How could this affect a DirectX application in such a manner?

```cpp
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name: MsgProc()
// Desc: The window's message handler
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
LRESULT WINAPI MsgProc( HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam ) {
    switch(msg) {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            Cleanup();
            PostQuitMessage( 0 );
            return 0;
        case WM_PAINT:
            Render();
            ValidateRect( hWnd, NULL );
            return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc( hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam );
}
```

Comment: Which version of DX, Windows, and GPU driver are you using?

Comment: im using directx 9 , windows 7 and a gts 250 this has nothing to do with hardware i think.Because it runs fine just fine when i have ValidateRect present.

Comment: My guess is that it does have to do with hardware in the way the NVidia driver and GDI interact. ValidateRect() tells GDI "don't worry about painting this surface."  Not calling ValidateRect() would cause DWM (Win7 has this on by default and uses the GPU) to sync the surface between GDI and DX.

Answer (score 3):

Your application is slowing down because it is rendering far more than necessary. It is receiving a furious stream of WM_PAINT messages.

Windows sends a WM_PAINT message to a window when it thinks the window should be painted. It makes this determination based on whether a window has been invalidated. Once you have rendered the window completely, you must tell Windows that this is the case by validating the window’s client area. As long as there is some invalidated area, Windows will continue to send your window WM_PAINT messages.

Before DirectX, application windows were validated when they called EndPaint. You can still call BeginPaint and EndPaint, wrapping whatever DirectX rendering you’re doing, or you can simply call ValidateRect when you’re done rendering.